# How to exchange data in JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript

I have a problem wrapping my head around some basic object oriented JavaScript.
I'm not sure how to let classes communicate. Excample (I'm using Babel):

```
A class "ColorPalette" that has a list of colors
A class "Canvas" that lets you display a color from the ColorPalette colors
```

In my main script I instantiate both classes like

```
var colorpicker = new ColorPalette();
var drawingboard = new Canvas();
```

and then I can do e.g.

```
drawingboard.draw(colorpicker.getActiveColor());
```

So far so good. I understand how to work with getters and setters and I know that I can pass data to a method. Cool.

But often, I don't want the main script to handle every little detail, for example the ColorPalette should always know the most used color from the Canvas. But from within the ColorPalette class I should not know or care about the instance name of other classes.

So I can do this from my main script:

```
colorpicker.setMainColor(drawingboard.getMainColor());
```

but I can't really do it from inside the colorpicker class as the class should not assume the instance name of the canvas class ("drawingboard").
I'm pretty sure the problem is my bad thinking here. Therefore any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Add more of your code (class structure, relevant members of the class)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing context, but would `colorpicker.setMainColor(drawingboard.getMainColor());` not be in your main logic, outside of either class?

Answer (score 0):

I think that to achieve your goal of decoupling the classes from one another you need to use a design pattern like MV*, IoC, Observer or something else, it really depends on what you're trying to do.

The MV* is very popular in JavaScript, in it's most basic form you'll have a class that'll be responsible for translating user actions to ColorPalette and Canvas methods.

The IoC in JS is kinda messed up, but you can still do something like it. Basically you can create a constructor in `ColorPalette` which takes 1 argument - `Canvas` and stores it as a class variable. Then you can use this variable to extract needed data (e.g. most used color).

Events - you can use Pub-Sub or Observer or any other events based system to transfer data between classes and keep them decoupled at the same time.

There are a ton of other patterns which you can check to find the most suitable one.